# Photos from a website to android app

Tags: java, android, listview, jsoup

Im using ListView and Jsoup to create simple app that shows photos from a website, anyone can tell me why does the emulator crushes everytime? what's the problem with the code?

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
private ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
     listView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listview); 
     final ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

     Document doc = null;

    try {

        doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://mongol.co.il/").get();
        Elements divs = ((Elements) doc).select("img[src$=.jpg]");

        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element div : divs)
        {   
            list.add(div);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

Comment: Please add your crashlog.

Comment: Please provide error details from logcat.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mongol/com.example.mongol.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.nodes.Document   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: 04-20 12:52:46.061: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 12:52:46.061: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-20 12:52:46.061: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-20 12:52:46.061: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I had this also in my application.

The solution is fairly simple:

All Networking actions have to be done in an Asyntask or Thread

I personally use an Asynctask like this:

```
        private class LoadImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Here you can do any UI operations like textview.setText("test");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Document doc = null;

    try {

        doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://mongol.co.il/").get();
        Elements divs = ((Elements) doc).select("img[src$=.jpg]");

        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element div : divs)
        {   
            list.add(div);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This class shouldn't extends Activity? what about the onCreate method?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make http requests in your `onCreate`, this will throw an exception in ICS and above, *I think*, because you are blocking the UI thread.